# 3 kugels for 3 sifrei Torah?

Tags: minhag, food, torah-service, provenance, four-parshiot

When I was younger (yes, that did happen to me - ONCE :-) the Rav from the shul I attended would include a suggestion whenever there was a Shabbat where we use 3 Sifrei Torah, such as will occur this week.

He said that there is a custom to eat 3 different kugels - a potato, noodle (O.K., they called it *lukshen* then; now it's called "pasta" - same thing!), and rice kugel.

I'm older, (not my choice, believe me), the rav might be enjoying Shabbat in heaven, and I'm wondering where the source of this minhag originated from. Any ideas?

Comment: Boruch Hashem you are older. The cemetery is full of young people.

Comment: I just heard somebody at the store ask somebody at the prepared-foods section about this (apparently it started as "do you have three different kugels available?"), but I hadn't yet seen this question.  Bummer!  (No, nobody there knew.)

Comment: @GershonGold browsing around, and I saw your comment. I LOVE it, and if you don't mind, I'm going to use it on a few people. It's a great bracha!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps your Rav based it on Minhagei Komarna. [Minhagei Komarna - 235](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=5503&st=&pgnum=58&hilite=) says that the Minhag Komarna was to have 3 Kugels every Shabbos. When 2 Sefer Torahs were read they had 4 Kugels. When 3 Sefer Torahs were read they had 5 Kugels.

On the notes at the bottom it says that this is based on the [Be'er Hataiv 419](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49626&st=&pgnum=176) quoting the Sheyarai Knesses Hagdola and Sefer [Darchei Chaim V'Shalom 455](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4692&st=&pgnum=158) (a collection of customs of the [Munkatcher Rebbe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Elazar_Spira) and sources for said customs). Interesting to note that Darchei Chaim V'Shalom talks about 3 Kugels on such a week, not 5.

Comment: 5 kugels? Growing up, I could only fathom two types - potato and lukshen. You're right. It's a good thing that I am older. Now, I see broccoli, zucchini and apple kugel among others. So, it's "easier" to make 5, assuming your wife has the patience for this. Well - at least I have until this Nissan to worry about it...